# git merge default commit message has message from all merged commits

Tags: macos, git, jira

Our team uses JIRA's "smart commits" for time tracking. However, some users, upon merging branches, end up with a git merge message like the following.

```
 Merge branch 'master' into  FEATURE_BRANCH

 * master: (3 commits)

 ISSUE-108: Added logging dependency #time 30m
 ISSUE-110: Fixed a bug #time 1h
 ISSUE-118: Bikeshedding #time 4h
```

The problem is that for this user, merging has just "double-booked" 5h30m into JIRA via smart commits.

The most we've deduced is that users who have this happen are on Mac OS X with git 1.8.x, while Ubuntu users (who don't have this happen) are on git 1.7.9.5.

Reading the help docs `git merge --no-log` is the cause of this behavior. Did this change as a default between 1.7 and 1.8 (or between Mac and Ubuntu clients) and how do we (can we?) change the default to `--no-log` for all users?